# What are transaction costs likely to be after Casper?

Tags: transactions, gas-price, casper

It presently costs X to send a simple transaction.

Assuming the price of ether stays constant, what is a theoretical estimate for the new cost of the same sort of transaction after Casper? i.e X/10?